# Is it possible to cout an EM DASH on Linux and Windows?

Tags: c++, unicode, cout

I haven't been able to find a way to `cout` a '—' character, whether I put that in the cout statement like this: `cout << "—";` or use `char(151)`, the program prints out a fuzzy undefined character. Do you guys see anything wrong with my code? Is `cout`ing a EM DASH even possible?

Edit: I've also tried `wcout << L"—";` and `std::wcout << wchar_t(0x2014);`. Those both print nothing in my terminal.

Comment: @immibus Is there not a way to do it for both? In Linux, it prints the fuzzy rectangle character, in Visual Studio it prints a 'ú' character.

Comment: [How to print Unicode character in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12015571), [Printing UTF-8 strings with printf - wide vs. multibyte string literals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15528359), [How to output unicode characters in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17641718). In Linux, it's quite straitforward, just use UTF-8. In Windows it's a bit difficult. If the current codepage doesn't have an em-dash, the only way is using Unicode

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc \u0151 prints a question mark.

Comment: @LarryK where did I said that you print `\u0151`?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You never said it, but it was one of the answers in one of your links.

Comment: The unicode value for em dash is `0x2014`. I thought `std::wcout << wchar_t(0x2014);` is the right thing but I get two plain old dashes as output. It could be my terminal settings.

Comment: @RSahu For me, `std::wcout << wchar_t(0x2014);` prints nothing.

Comment: @LarryK, it obviously depends on the terminal settings. Good luck with finding a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, EM DASH is an unicode character (just making sure you do know that).

Printing unicode characters depends on what you're printing **to**. 
If you're printing to a Unix terminal (or an emulator), the terminal emulator is using an encoding that supports this character, and that encoding matches the compiler's execution encoding, then you can do what you just did above in your source code `cout << "—";`

If you're getting fuzzy undefined characters, it is possible that your terminal just doesn't support that character.

If you're in windows (where it is harder), you can do something like this (which is not portable):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"—";
}
```

Comment: it's possible that you're printing the wrong way. `wcout << L"—";` may work

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I tried that, it causes the program to print nothing.

Comment: like @LưuVĩnhPhúc suggested, I've updated my answer for windows

Comment: Sigh, I wish there was a universal way to do this, but that doesn't change the fact that you've given a very thorough and correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, we can't have everything :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no universal support for Unicode in C++ and in various terminals, so there won't be a portable solution.

The thing is that the Windows console uses codepages in console by default. It probably uses UTF-16 internally but will always convert to and from the current ANSI codepage when interacting with outside. So simply printing an UTF-16 code point like `std::wcout << wchar_t(0x2014);` won't work without any prior setup. You need to [switch to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14109024/995714) by running [`chcp 65001`](https://superuser.com/q/269818/241386) in the console or `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` in code before printing the character out  with

```
std::wcout << L"—";
```

It will not always work because of the worse Unicode support in Windows console. In many cases the characters don't appear due issues in the renderer or font, replacing with squares or `????`. But in that case just copy the text out and paste to any Unicode text box then it will be displayed properly

If you're using Windows in English or some other Western European languages that use [codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)/[ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) then you can print em-dash which is at the [codepoint 151](https://stackoverflow.com/a/631530/995714) simply by

```
cout << (char)151;
```

If it doesn't work then you're not on codepage 1252. You can change it to 1252 if possible or look up for em-dash in your codepage (if available)

On Linux things are much simpler because UTF-8 are used by default. So you can output the string as normal without resorting to `std::wcout`

```
std::cout << "—"; // need to make sure that std::string is in UTF-8
// or use std::cout << u8"—" to force the encoding
```

In fact you'll often get surprise results if you use wide strings on Linux. `std::wcout << L"—"` won't often work because of [some possible bugs in libc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7695592/995714)

---

That said, Windows 10 console now [supports UTF-8 perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131654/995714) and even allows to [use UTF-8 as the locale](https://superuser.com/q/1033088/241386) so if you don't need to support Windows 7 then **there's a universal method** to print any Unicode strings:

```
std::cout << u8"—";
```