# Printing em-dash to console window using printf?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, windows-console

A simple problem: I'm writing a chatroom program in C++ (but it's primarily C-style) for a class, and I'm trying to print, “#help — display a list of commands...” to the output window. While I could use two hyphens (--) to achieve *roughly* the same effect, I'd rather use an em-dash (—). `printf()`, however, doesn't seem to support printing em-dashes. Instead, the console just prints out the character, ù, in its place, despite the fact that entering em-dashes directly into the prompt works fine.

How do I get this simple Unicode character to show up?

Looking at Windows alt key codes, I find it interesting how alt+0151 is "—" and alt+151 is "ù". Is this related to my problem, or a simple coincidence?

Comment: The problem is the windows console uses code-page(s) not Unicode.

Comment: The problem is that em-dash is an unicode character and you try to print it in an ascii string

Comment: Try this std::wcout << wchar_t(0x2014); and read that thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029906/is-it-possible-to-cout-an-em-dash-on-linux-and-windows-c

Comment: you need or use unicode output `WriteConsoleW` or first convert unicode to multibyte by using `WideCharToMultiByte(GetConsoleOutputCP(),..)` for use in *A* output function

Comment: @RichardCritten - for windows console native is exactly Unicode. and if use unicode output - no any problems. the code-page this is simply current value for performing the conversion from multi-byte to unicode

Comment: @RbMm a C statement `printf ("—\n");` run in my Windows console outputs `ÔÇö`.

Comment: @WeatherVane - and so what ? you need use `WriteConsoleW` with `L"—\n"`. are you understand why error when you use ansi version ? because used another code page (by default `CP_OEMCP`) to translate your string to unicode (in your src your `CP_ACP` is used)

Comment: @RbMm which is why I ticked up the first comment from Richard.

Comment: @WeatherVane - the comment is wrong. windows is unicode system and unicode used almost anywhere. in console as well. windows console is unicode. when you pass unicode string to print - it print it as is. and L"—\n" displayed correct. when you use ansi function to output - console first **translate** multibyte string to unicode. error that your source code and console use **different** code pages for translate

Comment: @RbMm I did not realise at first you were talking about [Windows console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) and not Windows console.

Comment: @WeatherVane - i try say that for windows console unicode is native. all text printed as unicode only. when the *A* api version is called - all string data is first translated to unicode and then called *W* api version. error when used *A* version (or crt shell) in wrong code-page translation

Comment: The answer linked by @sata300.de is the key for doing this conveniently in many cases, i.e. call `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)` at program startup and use wide-character C/C++ I/O such as `wprintf` and `std::wcout`.

Comment: The upvoted comment from @RichardCritten is probably just worded vaguely. I think it's referring to how the console (e.g. conhost.exe) is decoding the bytes written to it using its current output codepage (i.e. `GetConsoleOutputCP`). I don't think the comment means the console in general doesn't support Unicode. Though regarding the latter, the console is limited to the BMP (e.g. a surrogate code displays as a default character rather than decoding UTF-16 surrogate pairs); doesn't support combining codes; and requires a monospace font with glyphs for the characters (manual font linking helps).

Comment: @eryksun - `current output codepage` - this is absolute incorrect sentence. the console output always in unicode. the `GetConsoleOutputCP` - this is code page to **translate**  multi-byte string to unicode, before display it

Comment: @RbMm, maybe you're just misunderstanding what I wrote. I said "the console ... is decoding the bytes written to it using its current output codepage" (the latter is Microsoft's terminology). For example, `WriteFile` is called with a byte string. In Windows 8+ this calls `NtWriteFile` for the given File on the ConDrv device. The attached console (conhost.exe) is waiting on `NtDeviceIoControlFile`, which completes with the request to write the given bytes to the target screen buffer. The console first decodes these bytes using its "output codepage" by calling `MultiByteToWideChar` and the like.

Comment: @RbMm, if you don't like the term ["output codepage"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleoutputcp), take it up with Microsoft.

Comment: @eryksun - but read next on this page - *A console uses its output code page to translate the character values written by the various output functions into the images displayed in the console window.* so this is used for **translate** but not for **output**. the output is always in unicode

Comment: @RbMm, I just used the name of the codepage that's returned by  `GetConsoleOutputCP`, i.e. "output codepage". You're taking issue with the name as far as I can tell. Nothing I said is wrong about the operations.

Comment: @eryksun - in this case this is bad written in msdn. correct say "translation codepage". and all why i try explain - all errors due incorrect translations (2 translations is used unicode->multibyte->unicode in most case with different code pages). only one way avoid this translation - use `WriteConsoleW`

Comment: @RbMm, the simple (but still non-portable) way is via `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)` and then use the wide-character CRT functions such as `wprintf`. It's not extremely efficient since the CRT ends up calling `_putwch_nolock` in a loop over the characters, and thus makes a `WriteConsoleW` call for each character. But this is interactive console I/O, so we don't need extreme speed and efficiency.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, with `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)` `wprintf` begin use `WriteConsoleW` (char by char) instead `WriteFile`. but i personally not understand at all - for what have all this problems with CRT and/or ansi output when can simply call `WriteConsoleW` and have no any problems at all

Comment: @RbMm, it's easier when writing cross-platform code and adapting existing code.

Comment: @eryksun - if try cross-platform code may be yes. anyway this is not easy. if write for windows only - need use `WriteConsoleW` and main - the `printf` any way display `—` as `-`. only `WriteConsoleW`  give correct display

Comment: You can also call `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)`. The `/utf-8` compiler option forces UTF-8 string literals. I wouldn't use this prior to Windows 8, in which case `WriteFile` to the console incorrectly returns the number of decoded characters written instead of the number of bytes written. Also, `SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8)` is useless for non-ASCII input in all versions because the console makes the buggy assumption that it's encoding to ANSI (e.g. 1 byte per character) when it sizes the buffer for `WideCharToMultiByte`, which fails and yet `ReadFile` 'succeeds' at reading zero bytes, i.e. EOF.

Comment: Actually in Windows 10.0.15063 (Creators Update) reading input containing non-ASCII characters in `CP_UTF8` (65001) is a bit 'improved'. Apparently before encoding now they simply replace all non-ASCII characters with a Unicode NUL, so it doesn't look like EOF at least. It's just that all non-ASCII input characters end up as "\x00" in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

the windows is unicode (UTF-16) system. console unicode as well. if you want print unicode text - you need (and this is most effective) use [`WriteConsoleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole)

```
BOOL PrintString(PCWSTR psz)
{
    DWORD n;
    return WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), psz, (ULONG)wcslen(psz), &n, 0);
}
PrintString(L"—");
```

in this case in your binary file will be wide character `—` (2 bytes `0x2014`) and console print it as is.

if ansi (multi-byte) function is called for output console - like `WriteConsoleA` or `WriteFile` - console first translate multi-byte string to unicode via [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx) and in place *CodePage* will be used value returned by [`GetConsoleOutputCP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleoutputcp). and here (translation) can be problem if you use characters > 0x80

first of all compiler can give you warning: *The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (number). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss.* ([*C4819*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173715.aspx)). but even after you save source file in Unicode format, can be next:

```
wprintf(L"ù"); // no warning
printf("ù"); //warning C4566
```

because `L"ù"` saved as **wide char string** (as is) in **binary** file  - here all ok and no any problems and warning. but `"ù"` is saved as **char string** (single byte string). compiler need convert **wide string** "ù" from source file to **multi-byte string** in binary (*.obj* file, from which linker create *pe* than). and compiler use for this [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) with *CP_ACP* (*The current system default Windows ANSI code page.*)

so what happens if you say call `printf("ù");` ?

1. unicode string "ù" will be converted to multi-byte
   `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, )` and this will be at **compile time**. resulting **multi-byte** string will be saved in binary file
2. the console it **run-time** convert your **multi-byte** string to
   wide char by `MultiByteToWideChar(GetConsoleOutputCP(), ..)` and
   print this string

so you got 2 conversions: `unicode -> CP_ACP -> multi-byte -> GetConsoleOutputCP() -> unicode`

by default `GetConsoleOutputCP() == CP_OEMCP != CP_ACP` even if you run program on computer where you compile it. (on another computer with another `CP_OEMCP` especially)

problem in incompatible conversions - different code pages used. but even if you change console code page to your `CP_ACP` - convertion anyway can wrong translate some characters.

and about *CRT* api `wprintf` - here situation is next:

the `wprintf` first convert given string from unicode to multi-byte by using it internal current [locale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyzd2bce.aspx) (and note that *crt* locale independent and different from *console* locale). and then call `WriteFile` with multi-byte string. console convert back this multi-bytes string to unicode

`unicode -> current_crt_locale -> multi-byte -> GetConsoleOutputCP() -> unicode`

so for use `wprintf` we need first set current crt locale to `GetConsoleOutputCP()`

```
char sz[16];
sprintf(sz, ".%u", GetConsoleOutputCP());
setlocale(LC_ALL, sz);
wprintf(L"—");
```

but anyway here i view (on my comp) `-` on screen instead `—`. so will be `-—` if call `PrintString(L"—");` (which used `WriteConsoleW`) just after this.

so only reliable way print any unicode characters (supported by windows) - use WriteConsole**W** api.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the comments, I've found eryksun's solution to be the simplest (...and the most comprehensible):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    //other stuff
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"#help — display a list of commands...");
```

Portability isn't a concern of mine, and this solves my initial problem—no more ù—my beloved em-dash is on display.

I acknowledge this question is essentially a duplicate of [the one linked by sata300.de](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029906/is-it-possible-to-cout-an-em-dash-on-linux-and-windows-c). Albeit, with `printf` in the  place of `cout`, and unnecessary ramblings in the place of relevant information.